# Previous Activity still present

Tags: android, kotlin, background, android-lifecycle, foreground

Is there a way to totally remove the previous activity?

**Explanation:**

I have a `SplashScreen` Activity where I am loading data, etc. and then when it finishes I am navigating to `MainActivity` like this:

```
startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
finish()
```

My `MainActivity` come in foreground, no problem here, but when I am `listening to Lifecycle Event` with `ProcessLifeCycleOwner library`, in this particular case:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun appWillEnterBackground() {
    Log.e("INACTIVE", "BECOME INACTIVE")
}
```

Both of my Activities are going on this method while I am on my `MainActivity`. My `SplashScreen` Activity should not be able to enter this method because I `finish()` it.

I tried to return after `finish()` , I tried `"noHistory=true"` in `Manifest.xml` but neither of those worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Who are the lifecycle observers? your activities? you might be leaking your splash activity

Comment: did you do something like this when finishing your splash: myLifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);

Comment: No I didn't do something like this , but I found a way. On my Splashscreen onDestroy() method I set up a boolean to false and then I use it wherever I want in order to skip steps where my SplashScreen activity were used "destroyed"

Comment: that's is not good solution you have to find the root of the problem. You might be leaking the splashscreen and that can cause problems later on

Comment: My Splashscreen do some call to webservice and get some data from Firebase . When I got everything via callback , when the process is finished I simply call start MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can try `finishAffinity()` method.

> finishAffinity(): Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in
>   the current task that have the same affinity.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately , In my "appWillEnterBackground()" method, I check the actual context and it enters 2 times in it. The first time it's the MainActivity and the second is my SplashScreen Activity

Comment: Try finishing SplashActivity before starting MainActivity. finish(); startactivity(..);

Comment: Same answer as below it doesn't work this way either

Answer (score 0):

First call finish method and then start new activity.

```
finish()
startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `singletop` launch type for MainActivity.

```
    <activity android:name=".SingleTaskActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver in the activity you want to kill. register it with an intent action like "ACTION_KILL_THIS_ACTIVITY". in onReceive method of this broadcast receiver add finish(); line. When your new activity starts, you are ready to kill the other one so from the new activity's onCreate() method, call

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("ACTION_KILL_THIS_ACTIVITY"));
```

Comment: And don't forget to unregister the broadcast receiver in the killed activity's onDestroy() method, otherwise you could leak memory.

Comment: if you want you killed activity to not apear in recently open apps, add this line in your manifest android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `applicationContext` pass the `SplashScreenActivity.this` as the argument, so your code will look like this:

`startActivity(Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();`